# filtering a paginated eloquent collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to filter a paginated eloquent collection, but whenever I use any of the collection methods, I lose the pagination.

```
$models = User::orderBy('first_name','asc')->paginate(20);

$models = $models->each(function($model) use ($filters) {
    if(!is_null($filters['type'])) {
        if($model->type == $filters['type'])
            return $model;
    }

    if(!is_null($filters['state_id'])) {
        if($model->profile->state_id == $filters['state_id'])
            return $model;
    }

    if(!is_null($filters['city_id'])) {
        if($model->profile->city_id == $filters['city_id'])
            return $model;
    }
});

return $models;
```

I am working with Laravel 4.2, is there any way to persist the pagination?

Comment: Why don't you do the filter before pagination?

Comment: @mininoz you mean manually paginate?

Comment: It's mean to SELECT only users with needed type and without null city and state and than paginate.

Comment: @MrFoh I've provided a more up-to-date answer for Laravel 5.2+ that actually modifies the underlying paginator collection.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Expanding on mininoz's answer with your specific case:

```
//Start with creating your object, which will be used to query the database

$queryUser = User::query();

//Add sorting

$queryUser->orderBy('first_name','asc');

//Add Conditions

if(!is_null($filters['type'])) {
    $queryUser->where('type','=',$filters['type']);
}

if(!is_null($filters['state_id'])) {
    $queryUser->whereHas('profile',function($q) use ($filters){
        return $q->where('state_id','=',$filters['state_id']);
    });
}

if(!is_null($filters['city_id'])) {
    $queryUser->whereHas('profile',function($q) use ($filters){
        return $q->where('city_id','=',$filters['city_id']);
    });
}

//Fetch list of results

$result = $queryUser->paginate(20);
```

By applying the proper conditions to your SQL query, you are limiting the amount of information that comes back to your PHP script, and hence speeding up the process.

Source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#querying-relations

Comment: That is a good answer, but it gives me bugs. It applies filters but it keeps the page number. If I apply a new filter, sometimes it sends me on a page that does not exist. For example, after filtering there was only 10 pages left, but when started filtering I was on the page 20. So it shows me no result and it does not highlights the page that I'm  on, because this page does not exist anymore in the selection

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev Please note that this answer is for laravel 4.2. The pagination system has evolved since then. Also, the count on the laravel pagination is known to be incompatible if you are applying complex filters (you can debug the latter by checking the executed mysql statements in laravel telescope).

Comment: The pagination should have been evolved, but your code is still working on Laravel 8 and the problem that you would have on laravel 4 is still there for laravel 8 users. :)

Answer (score 18):

An answer to the titular question, which is possible in Laravel 5.2+:

> How to filter the underlying collection of a Paginator without losing the Paginator object?

You can eject, modify and inject the collection as follows:

```php
$someFilter = 5;
$collection = $paginator->getCollection();
$filteredCollection = $collection->filter(function($model) use ($someFilter) {
  return $model->id == $someFilter;
});
$paginator->setCollection($filteredCollection);
```

The Paginator is built on an underlying collection, but indeed when you use any of the inherited `Collection` methods they return the underlying collection and not the full Paginator object: collection methods return collections for chaining together collection calls.

Comment: Thanks. Only issue I see here is that `filter` returns a new collection, doesn't modify the existing. Need to assign a new `$filteredCollection = $collection->filter->(...`

Comment: Absolutely beautiful

Comment: this does not update other vital properties like `total` and `lastPage`, so it breaks pagination.

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper those properties are protected and cannot be set directly.

Comment: After thinking some more it is logical: the `total` and `lastPage` are obtained by executing a count query. If you're filtering at the collection level you'd have to retrieve all query results, filter them and return the new count. You'd lose the purpose of pagination. This `get/setCollection` approach can still be usefull because you're just reducing the items per page by excluding unfit candidates. All pages will still work, they'll just contain less items than the page limit. I wouldn't say "so it breaks pagination" is correct.

Answer (score 7):

I have a scenario that requires that I filter on the collection, I cannot rely on the Query Builder.

My solution was to instantiate my own `Paginator` instance:

```php
 $records = Model::where(...)->get()->filter(...);

 $page = Paginator::resolveCurrentPage() ?: 1;
 $perPage = 30;
 $records = new LengthAwarePaginator(
     $records->forPage($page, $perPage), $records->count(), $perPage, $page, ['path' => Paginator::resolveCurrentPath()]
 );

 return view('index', compact('records'));
```

Then in my blade template:

```php
{{ $records->links() }}
```

Comment: the best answer ever to this question, it is the real acceptable answer.

Answer (score 1):

paginate() is function of Builder. If you already have Collection object then it does not have the paginate() function thus you cannot have it back easily.

One way to resolve is to have different builder where you build query so you do not need to filter it later. Eloquent query builder is quite powerful, maybe you can pull it off.

Other option is to build your own custom paginator yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do some query on your model before do paginate.

I would like to give you some idea. I will get `all users by type`, `sort` them and do `paginate` at the end. The code will look like this.

```
$users = User::where('type', $filters['type'])->orderBy('first_name','asc')->paginate(20);
```

source: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/pagination#usage

Answer (score 0):

This was suitable for me;

```
$users = User::where('type', $filters['type'])->orderBy('first_name','asc')->paginate(20);

if($users->count() < 1){
  return redirec($users->url(1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround when mixing search parameters and pagination, since default pagination won't keep the search parameters, using GET:

```
        $urlSinPaginado = url()->full();
        $pos=strrpos(url()->full(), 'page=');
        if ($pos) {
            $urlSinPaginado = substr(url()->full(), 0, $pos-1);
        }
        [...]
        ->paginate(5)
        ->withPath($urlSinPaginado);
```

sample generated pagination link: http://myhost/context/list?filtro_1=5&filtro_2=&filtro_3=&filtro_4=&filtro_5=&filtro_6&page=8

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this format in views

```
{!! str_replace('/?', '?', $data->appends(Input::except('page'))->render()) !!}
```

For newer versions of Laravel, you can use this:

```
$data->paginate(15)->withQueryString();
```