# laravel orm : sort by id but put 0 values of another column at the end

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a Products table

products: id, title, stock, price

I want new products to be at top of the list (first page), but I also want products with 0 stock to be at the end of the list (last page)

obviously, this doesn't work the way I want it, a new product with 0 stock still will show up first

```
Product::orderBy('id' , 'desc')->orderBy('stock' , 'desc')->paginate(20)
```

there are lots of similar questions but all seem to be about null values which don't work for me .. also I tried

```
->orderByRaw('stock = 0', 'ASC', 'id' , 'desc' )->paginate(20)
```

as was suggested but I get an empty collection

**it's a pagination query, sort has to happen in the database, and sorting the collection after reading them from DB won't work**

------------------------------------ EDIT ------------------------------------

i tried this code

```
Product::orderByRaw('stock = 0', 'ASC')
            ->orderBy('id' , 'desc')
            ->get()
```

which will generate this query in debugger

```
select * from `products` order by stat_view = 0, `id` desc
```

this code will work when i try it directly in database  , but for some reason in laravel i get an empty collection .... this is an old website which is using laravel 5.2 not sure if that has anything to do with the problem

[image]

Comment: You can use `sortByDesc()` method as `Product::orderBy('id' , 'desc')->get()->sortByDesc('stock');`

Comment: @EsTeAa sorry my bad , i had to be more clear  ... it's a pagination so sorting the collection after query wont work

Comment: You can actually sort paginated records. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56136996/3753055) for more information. You can use 
 the [sort](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-sort) method on a collection to provide your custom sort function. Works exactly like PHP's built-in [uasort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php) function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this.:

```
    $products = \App\Models\Product::select(DB::raw('CASE WHEN stock > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS priority', 'id', 'title', 'stock', 'created_at'))
    ->orderByDesc('priority')
    ->orderByDesc('created_at')
    ->orderBy('title')
    ->paginate(20);
```

First you sort by stock if it has more than one or more in stock and then by created_at (you need to have timestamps in the db) and then by title.

Comment: If you use MySQL you could use IF instead of case

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$products = Product::orderByRaw('stock = 0', 'ASC')
  ->orderByDesc('id')
  ->paginate(20);
```

Comment: thanx , i've edited the question .... any idea why im getting empty collections in laravel ?

Comment: @hretic the version is indeed a major factor you should've included in your question (add add it as a tag). Regardless of that, I think that should've worked but I haven't played much with that version

Answer (score 0):

You need to change order of your orderby functions

```
Product::orderByDesc('stock')->orderByDesc('id')->get();
```

Comment: thanx but i dont want to sort them by stock ... i just want stock=0 to be at the end of the list

Answer (score 0):

First sort by latest product and then by the stock that is zero, use the below code:

```
$products = Product::orderByDesc('created_at')->orderByRaw('stock = 0', 'ASC')->Paginate(20);
```